# How can I change the color of icons?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

How can I change the color of icons for moreNavigationController [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s281/sh/338992ff-1737-4af2-bce2-6350523066af/ca0a786a76ab269fd92d50f87e0ec2d0)

For tabBar i use the code:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"30cbff"];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Played here with this function;

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers;
```

like this:

```
for (UINavigationController *controller in viewControllers) {
    controller.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"30cbff"];
}
```

But without results;

Comment: Please share the code you've tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the image as a transparent area in a white image. Put this over a view and change the background color of the underlying view. That color will show through the transparent image and provide the colored image. Change the background image color for a different color image.

This is essentially the way the color iOS created for UITabBar images.

Get something like Spark Inspector (free demo), create a Tabbed Application and inspect to see how Apple changes the color.

Answer (score 2):

In IOS7 you can use tintColor to change Icon color.